# SimpleHTTPServer, shutdown and blocked request handlers

Tags: python, multithreading, http

I have an instance of SimpleHTTPServer, however when I try to call
"shutdown" on it and there is a request handler that is blocked - the
whole process will block.

It does so even if I run the "serve_forever" method in a deamon
thread.

See example code at http://codepad.org/cn8EYdfg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `shutdown` method won't take affect until after the `GET` request is processed.

And that request is blocking because of the queue operation.

Maybe this will help: [Stoppable Interruptable Python HTTP Server](http://blog.odegra.com/?p=3)

Comment: I've modified my code to fit what the post suggest (http://codepad.org/OV6zDRET), and it works. Thanks!